# Como Encriptar Variables por medio de URL

Tags: php, url

Me encuentro con un problema de seguridad en mi página personal. Al momento de redireccionar a una persona con un `header()` me encuentro con el problema que la URL me muestra todas las variables/role y nombre del usuario.

```
URL= "inicio.php?tipoUsuario=Empleado&usuario=1001299912&IdUser=1034"
```

Se que puedo utilizar `base64_encode` para encriptar variables por medio de link de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="pruebaAlerta.php?tipoUsuario=<?php echo base64_encode($tipoUsuario)?>">EnviarCodigo</a>
```

Pero no se como encriptar variables usando `header()`. Si alguien tiene un ejemplo que me pueda mostrar seria genial! De igual forma me daré la tarea de investigar.

Uso PHP.

Comment: Y si en vez de eso envías una petición POST? Usar Base64 es sólo ofuscar algo ligeramente y no resuelve el problema de seguridad, puedes ir a cualquier sitio en línea y correr el proceso inverso sin problema. Para redirigir a la ruta que deseas, pues pones la ruta dentro de header y ya, no es claro cuál es el problema (header sólo te va a redirigir a donde tú le digas y ya)

Comment: Ya lo habia intentando de esta forma :
`header("Location: pruebaAlerta.php?tipoUsuario=base64_encode($tipoUsuario)&usuario=base64_encode($usuario)&IdUser=base64_encode($IdUser)"); 
 `
**Pero** al momento de usar las variables me arroja (en la pagina que dirige ya puse el `$_REQUEST` entonces ese no es el problema) **�۬���**  

tienes algun ejemplo donde me pueda guiar ?

Comment: Las aclaraciones se ven MUCHO mejor dentro de tu pregunta, añadiéndolas (sin borrar lo que ya está). Puedes [edit] la pregunta tooodo lo que se necesite y va a ser más fácil leer lo que intentaste

Comment: Depronto podrías contar mejor cual es la intención de hacerlo? porque requieres encriptar unas variables en la URL? quizás haya alguna manera mejor en donde puedas hacer lo mismo que pretendes hacer sin necesidad de encriptar nada... pues normalmente las variables de la URL no se encriptan, entonces probablemente debe haber algún otro modo de hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Tienes que concatenar: `header("Location: pruebaAlerta.php?tipoUsuario=" . base64_encode($tipoUsuario) . "&usuario=" . base64_encode($usuario)" . "&IdUser=" . base64_encode($IdUser));` aunque, como ya te dijeron, esto no aporta mucha seguridad. Si no quieres que se vean los datos en URL, puedes guardarlos en variables de sesión.

Comment: Gracias !. si me sirvió,  les cuento, necesito que todas las variables esten encriptadas en el URL 
necesitaba que el header mande las variables por metodo GET al momento de terminar de hacer la validacion de un login, ese era el pequeño problema. Gracias !

Comment: `GET` no está hecho para enviar información sensible, por más encriptado que esté y si un atacante quisiera leer esta información, lo hará aunque uses `POST`, por qué no mejor usar **sesiones**, así también te ahorras los recursos que usas encriptando y desencriptando información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCION**
Se tiene que usar  al momento de mandar la variable por metodo GET

```
base64_encode($tipoUsuario)
```

Al momento de resivirla tenemos usar

```
<?php $tipoUsuario= base64_decode($_REQUEST['tipoUsuario']) ?>
```